# String processing in Python(as a list)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I need some advice. I need to write a program in Python that requests from the user a string `S` consisting of left
and right brackets, for instance `(()))(()(`.

After this, the program needs to count the number of left and the number of right brackets of the input string. For example, the string `(()))(()` contains four right brackets and four left brackets. Hint: introduce two counters initialized to zero in the beginning. Then explore the symbols of the string in a loop. For the current symbol increment the `left` counter by `1` f the symbol is `(`, otherwise, increment by `1` the `right` counter.

Then, I need to test whether the string is math-like.

Let us call a string math-like if the brackets occur like in a mathematical formula.
For instance, the strings `()`, `(())()`, `(()())` are math-like, while the strings
`))(())((` and `())(()` are not.
I need to write a program that prints `"YES"` if the input string is math-like and `"NO"`
otherwise. Hint: In particular, for each iteration of the loop, I need to check that the values of the `left` and `right` counters satisfy a particular condition.

I am just a beginner, so it is really confusing for me to write an implementation of this task or at least imagine how this should look.

I will appreciate any type of help, because I really need to solve this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a famous (and one of the most primary) application of the stack data structure. Try searching for 'parentheses matching using a stack'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're looking for someone to answer a course exercise for you. The main point of such a thing is that *you* work it out. So here's a starter, rather than a "here, give this to your teacher."

Token parsing requires more; so does paying attention to the *order* of the parenthesis. But here's how to run through a string and look at what you have:

```
test1 = '(()))(()('
test2 = '(()))(()'

def ptest(test):
    lefts = 0
    rights = 0
    balance = 0
    for c in test:
        if c == '(':
            balance += 1
            lefts += 1
        elif c == ')':
            balance -= 1
            rights += 1
    print 'testing "'+test+'"'
    print 'lefts='+str(lefts)+' rights='+str(rights)
    if balance == 0: print 'balanced, possibly math-like'
    else: print 'unbalanced, definitely not math-like'

ptest(test1)
ptest(test2)
```

Comment: This is part of a project which I am involved into, I am simply not a pro at programming, so it I really needed some assistance, and I am very grateful that you have helped me to understand what should I do, I really appreciate it.

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: My pleasure. Unfortunately, SO is pretty snarky about what is "OK." That's where all the anal-retentive downvotes came from. Sorry about that. Wasn't me. :)